# Multiplied e-mail addresses in Google Contacts

Tags: google-contacts

Each time I save an change (to any field) in Google Contacts, GC multiplies number of e-mails addresses I have for this contact, i.e. adds a new entry with exactly the same value.

When you look at contact summary, you see no difference (possibly GC "merges" fields with exactly the same value):

[image]

But when you turn into edit mode for the very same (or any other) contact you see:

[image]

Is this some kind of bug? Or am I missing something obvious in new Google Contacts functionality?

Comment: just tested it - looks like a bug on your side

Comment: You mean -- happens only in my case? From multiple computers and for about past two weeks? Sounds like a hard to believe.

Comment: no, I mean I tried to reproduce it based on your instructions and I failed. it does not multiply email addresses for me at all no matter what I try